# Repeating all rows of specific dates where dates missing using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['1-Dec-23', '1-Dec-23', '1-Dec-23', '5-Dec-23', '5-Dec-23', '5-Dec-23'],
        'Balance': [10, 20, 1000, 50, 100, 200],
        'ID': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# **Output**

index  Balance   ID
2023-12-01     10.0  1.0
2023-12-01     20.0  2.0
2023-12-01   1000.0  3.0 
2023-12-02     10.0  1.0
2023-12-02     20.0  2.0
2023-12-02   1000.0  3.0
2023-12-03     10.0  1.0
2023-12-03     20.0  2.0
2023-12-03   1000.0  3.0
2023-12-04     10.0  1.0
2023-12-04     20.0  2.0
2023-12-04   1000.0  3.0
2023-12-05     50.0  1.0
2023-12-05    100.0  2.0
2023-12-05    200.0  3.0
```

I have given input and Output required.Please solve.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not able to sort it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.groupby('Date').agg(list).asfreq('D',method = 'ffill').explode(['Balance','ID']).reset_index()
```

or

```
df.set_index(['Date',df.groupby('Date').cumcount()]).unstack().reindex(pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(),df['Date'].max())).ffill().stack().droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
         Date Balance ID
0  2023-12-01      10  1
1  2023-12-01      20  2
2  2023-12-01    1000  3
3  2023-12-02      10  1
4  2023-12-02      20  2
5  2023-12-02    1000  3
6  2023-12-03      10  1
7  2023-12-03      20  2
8  2023-12-03    1000  3
9  2023-12-04      10  1
10 2023-12-04      20  2
11 2023-12-04    1000  3
12 2023-12-05      50  1
13 2023-12-05     100  2
14 2023-12-05     200  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you are looking to do is, starting with 2023/12/01, populate a data frame with your given balances every 3 occurrences. You can do this with a for loop as follows;

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 1)

df_date = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Balance','ID'])

data = [10.0,20.0,1000.0,50.0,100.0,200.0]
id_list = [1,2,3]

dates = []
balances = []
IDs = []

for count in range(13): 
  if count == 0:
    dates.append(start_date)
    dates.append(start_date)
  dates.append(start_date)
  if count %3 == 0:
    start_date += datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    balances.append(data[0])
    balances.append(data[1])
    balances.append(data[2])
    IDs.append(id_list[0])
    IDs.append(id_list[1])
    IDs.append(id_list[2])

  if count == 12:
    balances.append(data[3])
    balances.append(data[4])
    balances.append(data[5])

del balances[12:15]

df_date['Date'] = dates
df_date['Balance'] = balances
df_date['ID'] = IDs


df_date
```